# Absolute Class on top of another Absolute Class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an absolutely positioned class (select) to be on top of another absolutely positioned class (drawer). I've tried several solutions but I couldn't make any of them work. Also, it appears that neither z-index will make it work.

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSD25.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYN4q.png)

CODEPEN:

https://codepen.io/Luis-Henrique-Valgoi/pen/bGmzeNp

```js
var label = document.querySelector('.label');
var select = document.querySelector('.select');

var clickHandler = function() {
  select.classList.toggle('hidden');
};

label.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.drawer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  background-color: green;
}

.label {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 20px, 0px);
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  will-change: transform;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.select.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="field">
    <div class="input">
      <p>field</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="input">
      <p>field</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="label">
      <p>select</p>
    </div>
    <div class="select hidden">
      <p>option 1</p>
      <p>option 2</p>
      <p>option 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. This will ensure future readers can benefit from answers, even if the external resources go down. Also it looks like there are some permissions issues with your example, getting access denied when trying to access.

Comment: @DanielBlack tks for the info. I've updated my question.

Comment: This happens because your `.drawer` has `overflow-hidden`. If you remove it the whole red square will be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple absolute positioned elements, to control how they are stacked, you can assign a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to each absolute container and give it a number. The larger number overlaps the rest.

But for this case it looks like your `.drawer` class has a style of `overflow: hidden;` which will clip any content that flows outside the container. Line commented in demo.

```js
var label = document.querySelector(".label");
var select = document.querySelector(".select");

var clickHandler = function () {
    select.classList.toggle("hidden");
};

label.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.drawer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
/*     overflow: hidden; */
}

.field {
    position: relative;
}

.input {
    background-color: green;
}

.label {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 20px, 0px);
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    will-change: transform;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.select.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
    <div class="field">
        <div class="input">
            <p>field</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="input">
            <p>field</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">
            <p>select</p>
        </div>
        <div class="select hidden">
            <p>option 1</p>
            <p>option 2</p>
            <p>option 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jesus Christ. Thank you so much! I've spent hours trying to figure that out. I was considering using Portal (this is a POC, but I have a REACT app with this real word problem). Anyways, It turns out that the overflow was a leftover from an old code.